# Where do thoughts come from?

Tags: truth, identity, subjectivity

When the next thought comes, try to catch its source.

Is there an entity "you" there? Or does the thought come from silence/nothingness? Is this "you" is just a thought that comes from this silence/nothingness?

Also, notice how effortless a thought appear, this can help with the "what's the source of our thoughts?".

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: Thoughts "come from" brain.

Comment: The question needs more content. Was there a particular event, or a specific line of thought, that brought this question to mind?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I don't understand how thoughts can come simply from the brain and nothing else. Because thoughts are abstract, while the brain is an object. Furthermore, the brain is relatively finite compared to the virtually unlimited capacity of the mind for ideas. It seems the mind is part of an electromagnetic field, which source is the brain and body. But it ought to be able to communicate with other electromagnetic fields, too

Comment: My thoughts come from me. My self is the sum total of all of my senses + all of my memories. There is no silence / nothingness here. My mind is working constantly, even while I'm sleeping. The silence / nothingness will come later, when I'm dead and gone. Apparently.

Comment: It is a well-used meditation method to pay close attention to the origin of thoughts and can be fascinating. The odd thing is that the more one focuses on their origin the less they appear, and with a complete focus on their origin they stop appearing. It seems to a case of 'A watched pot never boils'.

Answer (score 2):

The popular Western idiom "I think therefore I am" is grammatically construed. Indo-Germanic grammar demands verb to have a subject. This is why we say "it's raining" although the rain and the raining are one and the same thing. There is no separate actor for rain in the real world. The same can be arguably said of thinking. In cultures that (historically) have languages in which this grammatical rule does not exist (e.g. some Asian languages), it is often stated that the self is an illusion For example, in Buddhism, thoughts are said to [arise from the *non*-self](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mind-indian-buddhism/).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty clear that I am the one thinking.  Otherwise, how could people differ so much in opinion?  And how could education / awareness change a person's thinking?

Comment: I believe the question is not so much about "who" as about "how". I.e. while I'm aware that I'm thinking, I do not have the same awareness of how an *idea* is formed. Some ideas are constructs, in which case I can at best 'see' how the parts are linked. But basic, atomic thoughts have an elusive origin (when meta thinking are turned on it). Consider the process of composing, an artist will frequently say: " The music just came to me."